# How can I tell cargo to run code test in documentation in my README.md?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, doctest, readme

I'm looking for a way to move some docs from lib.rs to README.rs so they show up on my crate on cargo. I moved the docs to `README.rs`, and added this to the top of `lib.rs`

```
#[doc(include="../README.md")]
```

But it generates an error that says

> use `doc = include_str!` instead: `#[doc = include_str!("../README.md")]` **warning: this was previously accepted by the compiler but is being phased out; it will become a hard error in a future release! note: for more information, see issue #82730 https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/82730**

When I however migrate to use `#[doc = include_str!("../README.md")]`  instead of `#[doc(include="../README.md")]`, I get a warning,

> warning: unknown `doc` attribute `include_str`

And then

> warning: this was previously accepted by the compiler but is being phased out; it will become a hard error in a future release! note: for more information, see issue #82730 https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/82730

What is the proper syntax to get my `README.md` tested with `cargo test`?

Comment: "When I however migrate to use #[doc = include_str!("../README.md")] instead of #[doc(include="../README.md")], I get a warning, `warning: unknown doc attribute include_str`" – that should work, at least on a reasonably current Rust version. It does in [a package of mine](https://github.com/EliasHolzmann/include_optional/blob/301f14a169fe0ce76450629ff2d0b5dda4c4af8d/src/lib.rs#L5).  Are you sure you are writing `include_str!` and not `include_str` (without the exclamation mark) by accident?

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustdoc/the-doc-attribute.html -> `#[doc = include_str!("../README.md")]` - you need Rust >= 1.54 https://blog.guillaume-gomez.fr/articles/2021-08-03+Improvements+for+%23%5Bdoc%5D+attributes+in+Rust

Comment: @SvetlinZarev I'm using rustc 1.56.0-nightly

Comment: @SvetlinZarev I updated my nightly and that problem went away, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The right syntax is,

```
#[doc = include_str!("../README.md")]
```

On the latest Rust, this will **not** generate a warning, of note though is that this doesn't show up separately in `cargo test`.

If you have a failed test for example in your `../README.md` you'll see it reported as,

```
test src/lib.rs - sequence (line 22) ... FAILED
```

That seems far from ideal, as the name of the file is lost and the line numbers are no longer relevant.